# Reliably verify file is valid JPG

Tags: validation, jpeg

I've made a script that extracts JPGs from any file using JPEG magic numbers (data starts with FFD8, ends with FFD9).

However it's not enough, as a lot of data segments with JPEG magic numbers are not actual JPEGs, just other random bits of data, and will throw an error if you attempt to open them as JPEGs.

What are some additional byte checks that can be done to verify the validity of a JPEG file (markers that will exist in EVERY jpeg).

Comment: If you want to do a proper job of validation, why not just load the JPEG using your favorite image-loader library or utility?  If the image-load function call succeeds, call it good; if it fails, call it bad.

Comment: The JFIF file format has many other markers aside those, anyway, they are not strictly positioned, may depend on the content. Just google for it. But if you dont need extra performance, trying to decode using an existing libary might suffice.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner My utility is browser-based, have a look: https://x0a.github.io/thumbdata3-viewer/ Although img.onerror can definitely determine the validity of an image, it's a bit expensive for a 5gb file that may contain 10000s of matching segments. So a good binary check would do wonders, if I could find one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer depends upon the level of checking you want to do. Every JPEG stream should have an SOI marker at the start and an EOI marker at the end. In theory there could be data after the EOI market that is outside the JPEG image.

The next level down, you could check if there is an SOFx marker. There should be just one.

Then you could make sure there are sufficient SOS markers. In a sequential JPEG, there should be on per component. For a progressive JPEG, you need to do quite a bit more checking.

Then you could check that all the DHT and DQT markers required by the SOS markers are present.

Finally, you could check the scan data, which requires decompressing the image.

Comment: Just the kind of answer I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: Data after the EOI marker does not only occur in theory. Many, if not most camera manufactures pad their JPG files with null bytes after the EOI marker. The pictures from my Sony camera contain about 9000 null bytes at the end.

Answer (score 0):

A very reliable check I found was to find the start-of-frame byte marker (full table [here](https://dev.exiv2.org/projects/exiv2/wiki/The_Metadata_in_JPEG_files#2-The-metadata-structure-in-JPEG)).
`ff c0` or `ff c2`.

From there collect bytes until the header ends (with the start of a definition) `ff c4`, `ff db`, or `ff dd`.

Now you have a frame header. The first two bytes tell you the length of the header. Confirm that the number of bytes collected matches the value of the first two bytes. The header length is usually 16.

If the length between `ff c0 || ff c2` and `ff c4 || ff db || ff dd` does not match the value of the first two bytes, or if no such byte sequence is found, then its not a valid JPEG.